# Phase diagram of a fluid

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, phase-transition, density, phase-diagram

How is it look like the phase diagram of a fluid in density-pressure plane?  I came across the phase diagram in Pressure-temperature plane most of the time. But I can't find the phase diagram in density-pressure plane.

Comment: Isn't the density-pressure plane the same as the specific volume-pressure plane?

Comment: Specific volume is the insverse of density

Comment: So you are saying that you don’t realize that the PV plane is the same thing  as the P density plane?

Comment: How? Volume is inversely proportional to DENSITY.  and how the graph can be similar?

Comment: Are you saying you csn’t figure it out from a PV disgram?

Comment: A log-log plot of P vs V will be the mirror image of a log-log plot of P vs $\rho$.

Comment: I need desity vs pressure... PleasE show me the graph.

Comment: So you are saying that you don't know how to figure it out on your own from a P-V diagram?